# Should I put insulation in a shower wall if it's NOT an exterior wall?

Tags: bathroom, insulation, shower

I know that I should put insulation in a shower wall if it's an exterior wall, but what about if it's just an interior wall? Is there still a benefit to doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I would always insulate bathroom walls.  Bathrooms often have separate heat to keep them at a warmer temperature than the rest of the house so it's good to have the thermal insulation.

Just as important, it will also provide some acoustical insulation.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch, yes, it is usually electric - radiant floor heat, a single baseboard, in-wall units, ceiling heaters, etc. - not that it matters, insulation will help the bathroom supplemental heater maintain a higher temperature than the other rooms.

Comment: Insure there’s an adequate vapor barrier too. Vapor travels from warm side to cool side. (I would not use plastic sheeting.)

Answer (score 0):

Insulation would be a smart choice for the reasons stated by other users; however, ensure that the bathroom and tile grout is fully secured because once the insulation is wet then you have some serious mold issues. I often come across showers that have insulation soaked causing major microbial growth. Often times, entire enclosures need to be demoed in order to Mitigate all moisture. Just a quick thought.